# Are there any lightweight ASP.NET MVC-based frameworks supporting OpenID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid

I am looking for a lightweight framework that will allow me to knock out a MVC CRUD website very quickly, and I need it to support OpenID.

Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

According to this link https://www.ohloh.net/p/dotnetopenauth/download DotNetOpenAuth comes with project templates to allow you to "get started with a new web site that accepts OpenID and InfoCard right away."

I'll give that ago.

Any better ideas are welcome...

Update: It appears this template is for WebForms only... :(

Comment: dotnetopenid has MVC, ASP.Net and WinForm examples: http://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid

Comment: samples yes, but I am looking for something more like a template

Comment: The second link down on ohloh is a template.

Comment: so far i am using the dotnetopenid "sample" for MVC... would like a framework that could build me a DAL etc too. still a lot of low value work building a site up from scratch

Answer (score 1):

You could probably smush Asp.net DynamicData ( it has an unsupported MVC version ) and DotNetOpenId together pretty reasonable.

There is a "Secure DynamicData" example project at:
http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14473

In a nutshell it will involve changing the RouteHandlers to integrate with OpenId authorization.

Comment: ive used dynamic data in the past... not a big fan

Comment: Can I ask why you don't like DynamidData?